# Callback/event from Java timer

Tags: java, events, timer, callback

I'm writing a basic file monitor to check for new files in a directory. I haven't got a lot of experience with Java so I don't know what the recommended way of doing this is but here's what I have in mind:

1. Create a Timer and a TimerTask subclass to check for changes in a directory path
2. Dispatch event/notify back from the TimerTask subclass if the directory changed/a new file was added

I haven't done any event dispatching in Java but Googled a bit and found a lot of results revolving around swing/gui components which I'm not interested in at the moment. I was looking at the Observable class as well, but the issue is I need to notify from the TimerTask subclass which I can't do because I can't extend two classes. The project should be simple enough, a basic callback (passing a reference to a function from outside the TimerTask subclass to be called from within the TimerTask when conditions are met) would do.

What do you recommend ? What would be the simplest approach ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you could write a wrapper class which encapsulates the `Timer` and `TimerTask` into a self managed container.

This class could have the means to add/remove listeners and fire events to interested parties.

For example;

```
 public class FileWatcher {

      private Timer timer;

      public FileWatcher(File path) {

           timer = new Timer("FileWather", true);
           // Schedule task to start immeditaly and re-fire every second...
           timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new FileWatcherTask(), 0, 1000);

      }

      public void addFileWatcherListener(FileWatcherListener listener) {
           //...
      }

      public void removeFileWatcherListener(FileWatcherListener listener) {
           //...
      }

      protected void fireFileRemoved(File... files) {
           //...
      }

      protected void fireFileAdded(File... files) {
           //...
      }

      protected void fireFileChanged(File... files) {
           //...
      }

      public class FileWatcherTask extends TimerTask {

           @Override
           public void run() {
                // Look ma, no hands!
           }

      }

 }
```

Now, obviously, you will need to define the `FileWatcherListener` yourself, but that's a basic concept.

Now, if you're using Java 7, you could just use the [Watch Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) API instead

Comment: I think the best answer is in the last part of your answer -- using a WatchService provided by a FileSystem. 1+

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I agree, but I've got no context, the P may be using Java 6 or it might be a self teach exercise

Comment: This looks nice (+1), I'll give it a go...and yes, I'm using Java 6 (on osx :( )

Answer (score 2):

This should solve the purpose

```
ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                // Check Your Directory for changes
            }
        };

Timer t = new Timer(1000,al); // Timer(TimeInMilliSeconds, ActionListener) 1000ms = 1s 
t.start();
```

Comment: Which Timer class is this ? I'm using `java.util.Timer`

Comment: While I love the `javax.swing.Timer`, I'd be loathed to use it within this context.  Reading a file directory (and/or sub directories) is not the fastest of processes and would trigger a pause in the UI every second, which would drive me nuts :P.  The point about synchorising the UI is a valid one, but I'd use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` or even possibly a `SwingWorker` instead

Comment: The original poster has not stated that his problem is Swing-related, and so without this necessary bit of information, use of a javax.swing.Timer cannot yet be recommended.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am quite new to this community and still in my early learning stages, i tried to help the guy with the way i knew, I hope there's not a problem ! But i really appreciate you for explaining me why my method is not right. Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: edit: actually he states in his question that he is not using Swing and is not interested in Swing solutions, so given that, your answer is incorrect.

Comment: @IshanKhanna it's not meant as compliant or criticism, but as friendly feedback. Given the context of question (needing to possibly read a directory), I'd avoid using anything that might block the EDT -IMHO

Comment: looks like a quickfix, but I'm not using any swing classes/gui in my project at all. still handy thing to learn/know, thanks(+1)